# Trying to make a bomb diffusal text game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help regarding the random wire selector, what would be a good way to store/select the values?

```
import random

wires = ["yellow", "blue", "green"]
# need some help making this random wire selector
bomb = random wire
neutral = random wire
diffuse = random wire
# bomb, neutral, diffuse can't be equal
```

Comment: Note that diffuse and defuse are different things. As to your question, have you considered reading about Python's `random` module? This isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: good call, thanks for your help Jon

Answer (score -1):

For the wires

```
bomb = random.choice(wires)
```

Now you need to remove the element and random one of the other elements

```
wires.remove(bomb)
neutral = random.choice(wires)
```

And what's left is the third choice

```
diffuse = wires.remove(neutral)
```

There are if problems you need to always use ==

```
if input = diffuse (bad - this is an assignment not an equality)
```

For timing you need to use the time module https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html sleep is not what you need here. Timestamp after the user answers Y and then timestamp and calculate the difference to know how much time has passed.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense

Comment: i need to now attach a string to the random selector so that i can call it up when you try to cut the wire later on right?

Comment: random.choice(seq) returns a random element, not sure what you mean.

Comment: never mind, i appreciate your help. i realise this isn't a tutorial